# How to replace the old weka api Instance.missingValue()?

Tags: weka

I had developed a project using the old version weka jar about 4 years ago, and there was  one sentence `Instance.missingValue()` as I have replaced  the old weka jar file with the newest version, the IDE gives the error

> can not resolve the method missingValue.

I have read the api document of weka and found that the Instance class have been revised to the interface, but how to change the sentence `Instance.missingValue()`?

Answer (score 1):

### Background

Since Weka > 3.7.1 `Instance` has become an interface. In this context, `missingValue()` was moved to into `weka.core.Utils`.

### Solution

You can simply replace all occurrences of

`Instance.missingValue()` with

`Utils.missingValue()`.

*Source:

See this tutorial found in the [Weka Wiki](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/creating_arff_file/) (sub section on "Missing values").*

Hope it helps.